# Adding comments to article in Rails 5 (deeply nested resources)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app that has three main models: **Qn, Ans, and Comments**. I've been doing okay with 1-level-deep nested resources, but these three resources are *nested deeply* (Comments is shallowly nested) and they are all displayed in *one single view*, which makes it very confusing.

In a url like: http://localhost:3000/questions/2, the user can see all *@question.answers* displayed using a loop. In each of those *answers*, the user can see the *answer.comments* displayed using a loop. Below each *answer*, the user can also submit a new comment.

But after attempting several times to implement a 1) loop displaying all comments and 2) form for new comment, I always get some error along the lines of:

```
undefined method `model_name' for {:url=>"/questions/4/answers/2/comments/new"}:Hash
```

So I tried to pass in params *@commentable* instead of the *answer*, or point to **the specific controller and action** and so on, but none of these methods worked. I am guessing that I have an issue with my controllers to begin with, but I cannot seem to figure out what.

**routes.rb (top ommited)**

```
# Resources
resources :sessions
resources :users
resources :bookmarks # to be implemented later

resources :questions do
  resources :answers do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end
end
```

**Question model**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :answers
  has_many :bookmarks #later
end
```

**Answer model:**

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable

  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
  validates :answercontent, length: {minimum: 50}
end
```

**Comment model:**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**The show.html.erb (of QuestionsController)**

```
<% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
// ommited
<!-- Comments -->
<% answer.comments.each do |comment| %>
   <%= comment.content %>
   <br>
<% end %>

<!-- Submit new comment -->
<%= form_for(url: new_question_answer_comment_path, comment: {answer_id: answer.id, question_id: @question.id}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_area :content %>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**QuestionsController (new, create, destroy ommited for brevity)**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
def index
    @questions = Question.all
end

def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @answers = Answer.all

    # Delete only appears when num_ans is 0
    @deletable = (current_user== User.find(@question.user_id)) && (@question.answers.all.size==0)

end

private
  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:picture_url, :country, :educational_level, :topic)
  end

end
```

**AnswersController (edit, update, destroy ommited for brevity)**

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController

def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.create(answer_params)
    @answer.question_id = @question.id
    @answer.user_id = current_user.id

    if @answer.save
        redirect_to @question
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private
  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:user_id, :question_id, :answercontent)
  end    
end
```

**CommentsController**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
before_filter: load_commentable

def index
  @commentable = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
  @comments = @commentable.comments
end

def new
   @comment = @commentable.comments.new
end

def create
  @comment = @commentable.comments.new(params[:comment])
    if @comment.save
     redirect_to @commentable
  else
    render :new
  end
end

# From RailsCast ep.154
private
def load_commentable
  resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
  @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
end   
end
```

**The routes** 
are quite messy right now so I will just post where the comments are:

```
 question_answer_comments GET    /questions/:question_id/answers/:answer_id/comments(.:format)     comments#index
                        POST   /questions/:question_id/answers/:answer_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
new_question_answer_comment GET    /questions/:question_id/answers/:answer_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new
           edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)                                      comments#edit
                comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                                           comments#show
                        PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                                           comments#update
                        PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                                           comments#update
                        DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                                           comments#destroy
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Update:

To give you more info on what solutions I attempted:
1. Passing in two params like:

```
<%= form_for([answer, @comment], url: new_question_answer_comment_path(answer.id, @question.id)) do |f| %>
```

Gave me:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

2. Using @commentable (which is basically the answer) gives me an error saying that 'the id in @commentable.id doesn't exist as @commentable is nil'.

So I think the problem is that *answer* or *@commentable* is nil. But I specified it in the loop and in the controller too. So what else may I try?

Comment: shouldn't the route on the form be `question_answer_comments_path` instead of `new_question_answer_comments_path`?

Comment: @KarthikRavichandran To create a new comment, thats the route to be used actually.

Comment: @KarthikRavichandran You are right actually, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_for` expects **record** as *first argument*, in your case it should be a *comment instance*. Also <s>`new_question_answer_comment_path` expects values for `question_id` and `answer_id` keys</s>, as you are **creating a new comment**, the *route* should be `question_answer_comments` not `new_question_answer_comment` so your `form_for` should be

```
<%= form_for Comment.new,url: question_answer_comments_path(@question,answer) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

or just

```
<%= form_for [Comment.new,@question,answer] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes I noticed that and the error was fixed! Now I am working on the route, as when the 'submit' button is pressed i am redirected to 'http://localhost:3000/questions/1/answers/1/comments' instead of the original questions page, with a 500 error. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error during failsafe response: /Users/sophiepark/Desktop/miaoforum/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
before_filter: load_commentable // which is strange, because when I tried to submit 10 minutes ago, I got a 'no route for POST' error.

Comment: @SeHyunPark `before_filter: load_commentable` should be `before_filter: :load_commentable`

Comment: I learned this from here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised?view=asciicast and realised that I made a typo, should be before_filter :load_commentable. But this still gave a problem, so I used before_action instead of before_filter and it resolved the error (says the former has been deprecated). Thanks nonetheless!